# Filter JSON file on load?

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I have json data that I would like to filter based on user selection. For some reason I'm getting an error message in my debugger console: `TypeError: obj.contacts.filter is not a function`. Here is example of my code:

```js
var contactStorage = {};
$("#frm_find").on("submit", findContacts);

function findContacts(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var frmFilter = $("#frm_filterby").val();

  if (frmFilter) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/9j7qg?" + new Date().getTime(),
      dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(obj) {
      contactStorage = obj.contacts.filter(function(entry) {
        switch (frmFilter) {
          case '1':
            return entry.status === 1;
            break;
          case '2':
            return entry.status === 0;
            break;
          default:
            return entry;
        }
      });
      console.log(contactStorage);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('Error: ' + errorThrown);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form name="frm_find" id="frm_find" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="row find-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2">
      <select class="form-control" name="frm_filterby" id="frm_filterby" required>
        <option value="">--Choose--</option>
        <option value="1">Active</option>
        <option value="2">Inactive</option>
        <option value="3">Show All</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="frm_search" id="frm_search">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
                                    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

If anyone knows how to fix this problem please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: that would mean that `obj.contacts` is not an **Array** - and looking at the response, it is not an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contacts` is an *object*, not an array:

> ```
> contacts:{1: {id: 1, first: "Mike", last: "Johnson", email: "mjohnson@gmail.com", phone: "(203) 567-9055",…},…}
> ```

To use `filter`, convert it to an array first, perhaps via `Object.values`:

```js
var contactStorage = {};
$("#frm_find").on("submit", findContacts);

function findContacts(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var frmFilter = $("#frm_filterby").val();

  if (frmFilter) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/9j7qg?" + new Date().getTime(),
      dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(obj) {
      contactStorage = Object.values(obj.contacts).filter(function(entry) {
        switch (frmFilter) {
          case '1':
            return entry.status === 1;
            break;
          case '2':
            return entry.status === 0;
            break;
          default:
            return entry;
        }
      });
      console.log(contactStorage);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('Error: ' + errorThrown);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form name="frm_find" id="frm_find" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="row find-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2">
      <select class="form-control" name="frm_filterby" id="frm_filterby" required>
        <option value="">--Choose--</option>
        <option value="1">Active</option>
        <option value="2">Inactive</option>
        <option value="3">Show All</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="frm_search" id="frm_search">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
                                    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

If you want to transform the filtered array back into an object of some sort, you can spread it:

```
contactStorage = { ...contactStorage};
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. One more question, as you can see I use JS object to store JSON data once it's loaded. The problem is that will set data in array. After record has been updated, added or deleted I have to upload that data back to JSON file in the same format. Is there a good way to achieve that?

Comment: Do you need to *upload* data or just change/get a variable with the desired contents that your script has access to? Those are two very different concepts. If you want to upload data, you can use `fetch`

Comment: I have to pull data and display to the user. Then if user wants to add/edit/delete the data I have to upload data back in the same structure. Does that make sense? As of now I'm saving json data in JS object but that converts data into array. So I have problem uploading json data back to API in the same format. Can you please provide some example on how that can be achieved?

Comment: That's quite outside the question you originally asked - if you have a new question you should [ask a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: Actually solution that you proposed turns obj.contacts data in array and that's the problem. I do not want object to be converted to array. Instead I would like to filter an object and keep it as it is.

Comment: You can transform an object into an *array* and then turn it back into an object again after filtering, if you want. eg `{ ...filteredArr }`

Comment: That will just put array in the object. Still not the same as what the object looked like the first time.

Comment: If the original keys need to be preserved, then iterate over the entries and delete the key if the value needs to be filtered out. Please post your full question (including the expected output) *in your question* the first time you post it, to avoid this sort of thing

Comment: I do not want to delete the key if I'm filtering data. All I need at that point is to not include that record in the set of data. Thanks for your help.